# layerUsesCoreImageFilters causes glitch on first use

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

When I uses Views that are layer backend and have layerUsesCoreImageFilters=YES the first time I use a filter the view 'reinitializes'. Its pretty ugly.
I use a blur filter on a subview, but it causes the complete view to go blank and the reappear.
I am currently on Mavericks (10.9.4)
Anyway is there a standard method to force the initialization at app startup ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by setting layerUsesCoreImageFilters on some of my top level views before they were every displayed in awakeFromNib. This caused subsequent calls to setLayerUsesCoreImageFilters on other views to work properly without any drawing issues or flashing views.

Something like this in awakeFromNib:

```
NSArray *subviews = self.mainView.subviews;

for (NSView *subview in subviews)
{
    if ([subview respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayerUsesCoreImageFilters:)])
    {
        if (!subview.layerUsesCoreImageFilters)
        {
          [subview setLayerUsesCoreImageFilters:YES];
        }
    }
}
```